# Is it possible to right align the text in the last row of a justified textblock?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, paragraphs, ragged2e

is there a way to right align a text, which is at the same time justified? This particularly points onto the last line of the paragraph, which is normaly left aligned, or for example a very short one line paragraph, which would also appear as left alligned, although it is justified.

Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\leftskip` TeX primitive register saves the skip used at each left side of the paragraph line. The skip can be streatchable, for example 0pt plus1fil. The `\rightskip` TeX primitive register saves the skip used at each right side of the paragraph line. It can be "negative stretachable". It does not mean shrinkable, but it eliminates the positive stretchable amount from `\leftskip`. The `\parfillskip` TeX primitive register is set by default (by plain TeX for example) to 0pt plus1fil. It is added at the end of the last line of the paragraph. If we set:

```
\leftskip=0pt plus1fil
\rightskip=0pt plus-1fil

test text ...
\bye
```

then all lines of paragraph (but not the last one) have only `\leftskip` at left side and `\rightskip` at right side. Their sum is zero, so only glu between words are used for justification. The last line have -1fil form `\rightskip` and 1fil from `\parfillskip` at right side. Their sum is zero. But there is another 1fil from `\leftskip`. This skip is stretched and the result is like shown in another answer here. This another answer uses LaTeX specific syntax for setting TeX primitive registers.

Comment: That works for me, however, the other didn't work. I have tried to create a new environment with these commands, so that I could but only a specific text section into this format and leave the rest as normal. But this failed.


\newenvironment{justifyright}{\leftskip=0pt plus1fil\rightskip=0pt plus-1fil}{}


but it did not do anything, when using:

```
\begin{justifyright}
 \lipsum[1]\\
 \lipsum[2]\\
\end{justifyright}

Comment: This is a typical mistake of TeX users: First, you must to process `\par` command in order to format the paragraph with given setting, then you can close the TeX group. If you close TeX group first, then the setting is lost and the following `\par` command creates normal paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to balance the skips,

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\setlength\leftskip    {\stretch{1}}
\setlength\parfillskip {\stretch{1}}
\setlength\rightskip   {\stretch{-1}}

One two three One two three One two three One two three 
One two three One two three One two three One two three 
One two three One two three One two three One two three 
One two three One two three One two three One two three 
One two three One two three One two three One two three 
One two three One two three One two three One two three 
One two three One two three One two three One two three 



One two three One two three One two three One two three 
One two three One two three One two three One two three 
One two three One two three One two three One two three 
One two three One two three One two three One two three 
One two three One two three One two three One two three 
One two three One two three One two three One two three 
One two three One two three One two three One two three 
One two three One two three One two three One two three 
One two three One two three One two three One two three 
One two three One two three One two three One two three 
One two three One two three One two three One two three 
One two three One two three One two three One two three 
One two three One two three One two three One two three 
One two three One two three One two three One two three 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from wipet did the trick. I just wanted to post a mini example with a working environment definition.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newenvironment{justifyright}%
               {\justifying
                \leftskip=0pt plus1fil
                \rightskip=0pt plus-1fil}%
               {\par}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\begin{justifyright}
    \lipsum[1]
    \lipsum[2]
    \lipsum[3]
\end{justifyright}

\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]


\end{document}
```

Comment: you don't (ever) need `\justifying`, justification is the default.  This is essentially the same as the solution I'd postd except that you are using tex-primitive length assignments rather than the standard latex `\setlength` as I used. (wipet never uses latex,  so that's expectedin his case, but if copying it to a latex environment I'd use `\setlength`)

Comment: Oh ok, sorry for that. It wasn't that clear to me the difference between tex primitive and latex. I will try yours again and post here. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: also if you do use tex primitve assignments you should take care to terminate them correctly try this: `\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newenvironment{justifyright}%
               {\justifying
                \leftskip=0pt plus1fil
                \rightskip=0pt plus-1fil}%
               {\par}
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\begin{justifyright}
 Minuscule chances of error with such an environment if you use LaTeX syntax, but with primitiv assignments you need to be more careful.
\end{justifyright}
\end{document}`